# Getting Run time Error 5 when updating a Pivot Table

Tags: vba, pivot-table

I am trying to update a pivot table. The following code works on my computer but on my colleague's computer displays `Run time error 5 - invalid procedure call or argument`. The error accurs on `.ChangePivotCache` line

```
Sheets("DB for ECO Qty").Activate
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("ECO Qty over time Graph").Activate
DataArea = "DB for ECO Qty!R1C1:R" & LastRow & "C19"
Range("B4").Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
PivotCaches.create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=DataArea, _
Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: What version of Excel is your collegue running?

Answer (score 0):

The PivotTable object really was buffed up in Excel 2007, as it had really limited methods before that.

It is very possible that your collegue is running Excel 2003 and from this [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174280%28v=office.11%29.aspx), it doesn't seem like the `.ChangePivotCache` method exists in that version.